# inserting last login in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a login script and I want to insert last login into members table and update it everytime a member logins in but I am having some issues. The lastlogin is not being inserted everytime a user logins in. Here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($username,$password)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        try{
            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE admin  SET login_date = now()');
        }

        catch (PDOExeception $e){
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    } 
  else {      
           $error[] =              
                      '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in text-center">
                           <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                           <strong>Error!</strong> 
                            Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.
                      </div>';
    }

}
```

Comment: you're trying to update your entire db and you should be getting an error back about it

Comment: .... that too ^ once you do that.

Comment: someone just deleted their comment I was responding too about where you're executing and I smell an answer coming up. I sure hope they cover all the bases here

Comment: WIth this Query you will Update login_date of all Users. Probably you need to specify a WHERE-Statement.

Comment: aside from the already mentioned 'updating all records' thing. this piece of code should be inside the user class' login method too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be two errors with your above code.

1. The `UPDATE` has no where clause so it will update `login_date` for all rows in the `admin` table.
2. You create a PDOStatement object by calling `prepare()` on `$db` but never execute the statement. You need to execute the statement by calling `$stmt->execute()` after you declare `$stmt`.

Your code should look something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($username,$password)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        try{
            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE admin  SET login_date = now() WHERE x = y');
            $stmt->execute();
        }

        catch (PDOExeception $e){
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    } else {      
           $error[] =              
                      '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in text-center">
                           <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                           <strong>Error!</strong> 
                            Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.
                      </div>';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You are **not executing the query**
2. Add **`WHERE` for username**
3. You need session start

   ```
   session_start();

   if($user->login($username,$password))
   {
       $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

       try
       {
           $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE admin SET login_date = now() WHERE username =:username');
           $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
           $stmt->execute();
           $stmt->CloseCursor();
           $stmt=null;
       }
       catch (PDOExeception $e)
       {
           $error[] = $e->getMessage();
       }

       header('Location: index.php');
       exit;
   } 
   else
   {      
       $error[] =              
                   '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in text-center">
                       <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                       <strong>Error!</strong> 
                       Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.
                   </div>';
   }
   ```

Comment: Lol i was arraging the post. When i was writing the code and arraging someone posted between. And the solution provided is missing something! Sorry will be carefull next time!

Comment: Downvote reversed for a working / accepted solution. Fixed formatting to bring it up to same quality as other question. SO allows restricted set of embeded html code so in order to literally use `<?php`, you have to escape it first or leave it out (better to leave it).

Answer (score -1):

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

    require_once('connection.php');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[user_log]
           ([username]
           ,[login_date]
           )
     VALUES
           ('$_SESSION[username]'
           ,GETDATE()
           )";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

    if ($result === false ) { echo "Error in query "; 
    exit(); 
    }
```

> i had the same issue then i resolved by using simple codes as those
>   ones