# Updating last login time anytime a user login phpmysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a login script and I want to insert last login into members table and update it every time a member logins in but I am having some issues. The `lastlogin` is not being inserted everytime a user logins in. Here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($username,$password)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        try{
            $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE admin  SET login_date = now() where adminID = $adminID ");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt=null;
            }
        catch (PDOExeception $e){
                $error[] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    } 
  else {      
           $error[] =  '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in text-center">
                           <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                           <strong>Error!</strong> 
                            Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.
                      </div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't you just post this earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45305203/1415724 and got answers for it.

Comment: not really, there was problem with query that was what I got the answer for but now I have fixed the problem but still record is not being updated

Comment: question's unclear then and missing code

Comment: Personally, I think you accepted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45305508/1415724) *"just cuz"*.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didnt point the where clause in the first question, but now I have put the where clause but still the admin table is not being updated

Comment: How vulnerable is your password?! why aren't you using `password_hash() / password_verify()`?

Comment: @SamBanana you've an answer below now, see that. Personally, I don't see how that would solve this.

Comment: Where do you set your $adminID?? You may mean $username??

Comment: ^ that's the *unclear* part I was saying earlier. I'm betting it's undefined, or has no value. If it is an undefined variable problem, then your question will be closed with a duplicate for it. Error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have been something that would have helped, should this be the case.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is the login page so I want the login session id to be passed to the query

Comment: Perhaps the admin id is stored in a session variable??

Comment: Your logic is incorrect, if there was an error in the SQL query would never be displayed. Put the "header" and the "exit" at the end of the "try".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [inserting last login in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305203/inserting-last-login-in-mysql)

Comment: @fitorec putting the header and exit at the end of the try wont work... every try should be followed by catch.

Comment: @iehrlich theres no duplication insert, the record does not just insert.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logic of errors array, try with (or similar):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if ($user->login($username,$password)) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE admin  SET login_date = now() where adminID = $adminID ");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt=null;
        } catch (PDOExeception $e){
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password ...';
    }
}
if (empty($error)) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
// show errors
foreach($error => $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your SQL Query String you are not providing the adminID variable, instead you are fetching a user who has the adminID equal to the String value "$AdminID", the right way to put variables in a SQL query using PDO is by using prepare with tokens referring to the variables, then giving an array that associates each token to a PHP variable, like this :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE admin  SET login_date = now() where adminID = :adminID");
$stmt ->execute(array(':adminID' => $adminID));
```

In this way you protect you site from SQL Injections.

Comment: can you *explain* the answer and *how* that would solve the question? rather than just dropping code.

Comment: the adminID is not a place holder

Comment: All you did was add prepared statements.  I don't think this solves OP's problem